# jquery tab problem and delete question

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, tabs, forum

im working on a site and i have making a jquery tab but i want to do if i have select number 2 on the tab and then refresh i want it to remember what tab i have selected, so it dont fall back to nr 1 again but stays at the selected tab.

here is my site: http://www.rapcom.dk its the tab on the right

i have a little problem to and its when i click on the links in the tab menu it dont show the page but hide all the content on the jquery tab :S.

on the same website i have a forum and i want people to remove the comments if they want, how can i do that?

Thanks so much

Comment: You might want to ask your second question in a separate SO question as it covers a different problem.  If so, edit this question to remove it so as not to get your new one flagged as a duplicate.

Comment: You might also check out the very similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5338644/remember-tab-pressed-across-website/5338808#5338808

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [cookie plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie) with the tab plugin and remember the selected tab in a cookie.  See the tab plugin [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Tabs) for more information on the cookie option.

```
 $( ".selector" ).tabs({ cookie: { expires: 30 } });
```